# Can you add a URL to another server from Hyperion Workspace 9.3.1?

Tags: business-intelligence, workspace, hyperion

I'm new to the Hyperion Workspace world, so hopefully there's an obvious answer to this question.  Basically, I want to be able to add a simple URL link to one of the folders within a Hyperion Workspace (v 9.3.1).

I've found information on SmartCuts, which appear to be local links to reports which are served up by the Hyperion server; however, I want to be able to drop links to reports on other servers (e.g. SQL Server Reporting Services) elsewhere on the network such that users can see all available reports from one portal.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!